# Data is not inserted into SQL Server database from C# combobox

Tags: c#, sql-server

[image]

Data not being inserted into the SQL Server database after click on "Insert" button using C#. Stored procedure & image uploaded.

When I start the inserting, nothing is actually being inserted into the database.

```
public partial class test2 : Form
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=test;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=Rfl@123");

    public test2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        getRegion();
        int i;
    }
  
    public void getRegion()
    {
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("sptblRegion", con);
        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Region_Name"] = "Select Region";
        dr["Region_ID"] = 0;
        dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Region_Id";
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Region_Name";
        comboBox1.DataSource = dt;

        con.Close();
    }

    public void getState()
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() != null)
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("sptblState", con);
            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Region_Id", comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());

            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt2);

            comboBox2.ValueMember = "State_ID";
            comboBox2.DisplayMember = "State_Name";
            comboBox2.DataSource = dt2;

            con.Close();
        }
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getState();
    }

    public void getZone()
    {
        if (comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString() != null)
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("sptblZone", con);
            cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State_ID", comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString());

            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
            DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt3);

            comboBox3.ValueMember = "Zone_ID";
            comboBox3.DisplayMember = "Zone_Name";
            comboBox3.DataSource = dt3;

            con.Close();
        }
    }

    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getZone();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spRSZ", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "Insert");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Region", comboBox1.DisplayMember);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", comboBox2.DisplayMember);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zone", comboBox3.DisplayMember);
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to execute the command in `button1_Click`:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Side note, you [shouldn't use `.AddWithValue()`](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).  It's pretty much a bug waiting to happen.